# Whats wrong with my multipart/alternative Email?

Tags: email, mime

I'm trying to build up my own Email sending class and it seems I have a bug with my MIME.
If someone could find the error or tell me about a working MIME Validator I would really appreciate that.

Thanks in advance
JD

```
To: me@mydomain.com
Subject: Test Alternate
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:SendMail.class.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: me@mydomain.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="MultipartMail53dfa8ade817e"
Message-Id: <20140804153717.EA93E160195@myDevice>
Date: Mon,  4 Aug 2014 17:37:17 +0200 (CEST)
X-RCPT-TO: <me@mydomain.com>
Status:  
X-UIDL: 706801872
X-IMail-ThreadID: c9b40003d631c851

--MultipartMail53dfa8ade817e
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="Alternative53dfa8ade8378"


--Alternative53dfa8ade8378
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Some Text content


--Alternative53dfa8ade8378
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


Das ist Text
-- 

Text

*Some more Text*
Text



--Alternative53dfa8ade8378--

--MultipartMail53dfa8ade817e--
```

Comment: "it seems I have a bug with my MIME" — What makes you think that?

Comment: I'm sending the mail to my email address, checking it with thunderbird but can't alternate between html and plain text. I've tried sending it from thunderbird itself with the same content, and it's working, but I can't see any difference ... So I thinks something is wrong with the format and I can't find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things "wrong" with your email:

Firstly, you have a non-header in your header:

```
To: me@mydomain.com
*Test Alternate*
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:SendMail.class.php
```

(`*`'s around the broken bit)

Secondly, (and probably your main issue with Thunderbird) is that your multipart/alternative has the child parts in the wrong order. The way that `multipart/alternative` is supposed to work is that the last part is supposed to be the form that is closest to what the original author of the message intended for you to see (IOW what he/she saw in their WYSIWYG editor).

TL;DR

Put the `text/html` part last and the `text/plain` part first within the `multipart/alternative`.

Comment: Thanks, switching text/plain and text/html did the trick, thank you very much, I didn't think, that the positioning of those would be relevant ... The *Test Alternate* seems to be copy paste error, thats the Subject: line ;-)

Comment: From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html (See 7.2.3 The Multipart/alternative subtype) you get: `... In particular, each of the parts is an "alternative" version of the same information. User agents should recognize that the content of the various parts are interchangeable. The user agent should either choose the "best" type based on the user's environment and preferences, or offer the user the available alternatives. In general, choosing the best type means displaying only the LAST part that can be displayed.` This makes the order important.